# Cannot read property 'MessageList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to, MessageList push this values but I get error.

Error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageList' of undefined"

Also when I delete item.Message List.removeAll(); I take this error "result undefined" 
This is my bindList and I take error this block

```
   function bindList(data) {

    try {
    var results2 = ko.observableArray();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.list, {}, results2);
    item.MessageList.removeAll();

    for (var i = 0; i < results2().length; i++) {

        item.MessageList.push(
            new forum(
                results()[i].threadID(),
                results()[i].sender(),
                results()[i].files(),
                results()[i].messagesStatus(),
                results()[i].createdDate(),
                results()[i].forumMessageID(),
                results()[i].message(),
                //results()[i].whoReplyForumMessageID(),
                results()[i].CreatedByUserId,
                results()[i].senderID,
                results()[i].thread

            )
        );
        }
    }

    catch(err) {
        console.log("Hata"+err);

    }
}
```

Here is my LoadFromServer

```
 function LoadFromServer(id, eid) {

    blmsCommon.showLoading();

    var json = {};
    json.id = id;
    json.eid = eid;
    console.log(json);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'/Forum/GetMessages',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { id: JSON.stringify(json) },
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //var totalC = data.totalCount;
           // var itemCountInPage = data.countInPage;

                bindList(data);
                blmsCommon.hideLoading();
                console.log(data);
            console.log("LoadFromServer");


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }       
    });
}
```

I created view model with knockout and I created "var item;"

```
 var viewModel = function () {       
    var self = this;
    this.threadId = ko.observable();
    this.sender = ko.observable();
    this.files = ko.observable();
    this.messagesStatus = ko.observable();
    this.CreatedDate = ko.observable();
    this.forumMessageID = ko.observable();
    this.message = ko.observable();
   // this.whoReplyForumMessageID = ko.observable();
    this.CreatedByUserId = ko.observable();
    this.senderID = ko.observable();
    this.thread = ko.observable();
    this.MessageList = ko.observableArray();

    /*paging*/
    this.currentPageNumber = ko.observable();
    this.totalPageNumber = ko.observable();
    this.totalCount = ko.observable();
    this.firstIndex = ko.observable();
    this.lastIndex = ko.observable();
    this.order = ko.observable();
    /*paging*/
}

var item;
```

Comment: Your observable does not have a .removelAll() property at the time ko is evaluating the binding expression.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have not initialized your MessageList at the start. try doing :

```
var MessageList = [];
```

when you declare MessageList for the first time.

Comment: I have already done.       `this.MessageList = ko.observableArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You need use `new viewModel()` instead of `viewModel()`.
Because [New Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) create instance of `viewModel` type.
This will help you know more about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.